# Assign list of DataPoint to series Points

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I've got

```
List<DataPoint> p = new List<DataPoint>();
      p.Add(new DataPoint(1, 4));
      p.Add(new DataPoint(2, 8));
```

is any other way than using loop to assign this list to series.Points ??

Comment: Where in your code is `series.Points`? What does it refer to?

Comment: No, DataPointCollection doesn't have AddRange not even an constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [Series.Points.DataBindXY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467754%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.
Unfortunately, this method may seem inconvenient because of it's arguments are non-generic `IEnumerable`s.